# Fitting lognormal and normal in one plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have to fit lognormal and normal to my data on one plot in order to compare them. I was able to fit normal to my data which looks like the figure below. I'm having a hard time adding the fitted lognormal
[image]

Here is my code:

```
   mu, std = st.norm.fit(data)
   plt.hist(data, 50, density=True, facecolor='orange', alpha=0.75)
   xmin, xmax  = plt.xlim()
   x = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,100)
   p = st.norm.pdf(x, mu, std)
   plt.plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=1.5)
   plt.show()
```

Comment: scipy distributions are tricky. I made a library to help with them: http://phobson.github.io/paramnormal/tutorial/fitting.html

Comment: @JohanC yup it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`stats.lognorm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html) works similar to `stats.norm`, but 3 parameters are used. Having 3 parameters makes the distribution harder to fit, and often `loc` is given an initial guess of zero. Without such an initial guess, the fit is often quite poor. Note that instead of a guess, also a fixed `loc` can be set as `lognorm.fit(data, floc=0)`.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = 60 + (np.random.randn(50, 200)+0.2).cumsum(axis=0).ravel()

lshape, lloc, lscale = st.lognorm.fit(data, loc=0)
mu, std = st.norm.fit(data)
plt.hist(data, 50, density=True, facecolor='orange', alpha=0.75)

xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 500)
plt.plot(x, st.norm.pdf(x, mu, std), color='dodgerblue', linewidth=1.5, label='gaussian normal')
plt.plot(x, st.lognorm.pdf(x, lshape, loc=lloc, scale=lscale), color='limegreen', linewidth=1.5, label='lognormal')
plt.legend()
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: To try out [Paul H's library](http://phobson.github.io/paramnormal/tutorial/fitting.html) which can be installed with `pip install paramnormal`:

```py
import paramnormal

lognorm_params = paramnormal.lognormal.fit(data)
plt.plot(x, paramnormal.lognormal.from_params(lognorm_params).pdf(x))
```

At first sight, for these example data it gives the same curve (but with different parametrization) as `st.lognorm.fit(data, loc=0)`.